# Skip silence in playback - Optimizing values

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

My goal is to skip silence in playback.

This is my code

```
...
double v1 = 500;
float v2 = 0.005F;
double v3 = 40;
meter = new MeteringSampleProvider(AudioFileReaderObject);
meter.StreamVolume += Meter_StreamVolume;
meter.SamplesPerNotification = v1;
...                


private void Meter_StreamVolume(object sender, StreamVolumeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.MaxSampleValues.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", e.MaxSampleValues[0]);
        if (e.MaxSampleValues[0] < v2 && AudioFileReaderObject.TotalTime.TotalMilliseconds > AudioFileReaderObject.CurrentTime.TotalMilliseconds + v3)
        {
            Console.Write("Correction " + AudioFileReaderObject.CurrentTime);
            AudioFileReaderObject.CurrentTime += TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(v3);
            Console.WriteLine(" -> "+AudioFileReaderObject.CurrentTime);
        }
    }
}
```

The output either does not really remove silence or chops everything.

How do I optimize v1, v2 and v3?

Answer (score 0):

To skip silence in playback you'd need to implement your own `IWaveProvider` (or `ISampleProvider`) that reads ahead from the source. You could then find a noise gate algorithm to detect when periods of silence start and end, and then discard all samples during the silent period. Unfortunately this is something you'd have to implement yourself as it's not a feature of NAudio